# Pick the values from the corresponding max matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I don't think I asked the question right, so this example will make it easier for you to understand what I mean.

Lets say I have 2 matrices

```
A = [5,5; 7,7];
B = [2,2; 6,4];
```

And another 2 matrices, each one correspond with one of the above.
Lets say

```
A' = [7,7; 9,9];
B' = [1,1; 10,5];
```

And I need to construct a new Matrix, that will check each pixel in A' and B', pick the max, then goes to the corresponding Matrix and extract the value from there.

In this example I will get this newMat

```
newMat = [5,5; 6,7];
```

It is easy to be done with loops, is there a way to do it with out using loops ?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you expect to happen when `Aprime(k) == Bprime(k)`?

Comment: Doesn't matter from where the value then is taken. It could be taken from A or B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a logical matrix of where `Aprime` is more than `Bprime` and that can then be used to grab values from either `A` or `B`

```
aprime_is_greater = Aprime > Bprime;

% Initialize C to B and replace values where Aprime was greater
C = B;
C(aprime_is_greater) = A(aprime_is_greater);
```

Comment: Updated it to probably a slightly more efficient version.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach. Let your inputs be

```
A = [5,5; 7,7];
B = [2,2; 6,4];
Aprime = [7,7; 9,9];
Bprime = [1,1; 10,5];
```

Then

```
newMAt = (Aprime>Bprime).*A + (Aprime<=Bprime).*B;
```

Comment: I think you meant
newMAt = (Aprime>Bprime).*A + (Aprime<=Bprime).*B;
Works too. One code line is great.

Comment: @TonyTannous Whoops. Corrected